# Implement google play licensing library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-license-manager

Can some one help me to import the Google Play licensing library to my android studio project?

I have downloaded and installed everything that was available in the SDK manager, including the Google play licensing library.

But now I don't know how to import the lib to my project.

I have tried to go to /sdk/extras/google but there is no folder with the name of google_play_licensing?

I have also tried tho go to my project structure and add a library dependency but the lib isn't there either.

Where can I find the lib and how can I add it to my project?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html

Comment: I have read the article but Im still unable to finde the lib in the library dependency list.

Comment: try the setting up doc page, https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#download-lvl

Comment: you have to go to the folder where the android sdk is installed to,  then you will be able to get to `...extras/google...` goodies

Comment: I have added all folder from ...extras/google... to app\src\main\java\com and have syncronised and cleaned my project. But in this line private com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback mCecker; it says cannot resolve symbol vending